# jBCrypt alternative? Officially threadsafe, with a bigger community

Tags: java, security, password-protection, bcrypt, password-storage

To hash passwords (one-way), it looks like [bcrypt is the best](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

I am about to start using [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/), but I have a few worries:

- No mailing list.
- Very low activity overall.
- [Bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/issues/list) has only ever had 1 issue, and this 1 issue has not received any sign of activity.
- Only 3 versions have ever been released.
- jBCrypt does not claim to be threadsafe. While [most people seem to agree that the source code looks threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949415/is-jbcrypt-0-3-threadsafe), a clear statement on the official website would be much better.

Is there a similar, more mainstream library that everyone is using, and that I missed somehow? (Java, open source)
Or is it actually the "most mainstream" one?

Comment: It should be thread safe (http://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/issues/detail?id=2)

Comment: Now that the project is on Google and has a Google Group, maybe it will gain more traction.  http://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/

Comment: FWIW, the cited question (and accepted answer) claiming that jBcrypt is not threadsafe is dubious / wrong.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949415/is-jbcrypt-0-3-threadsafe for more recent information.

Comment: its now on github
https://github.com/djmdjm/jBCrypt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BCrypt is a clever but 'simple' algorithm. The Java code is 700 lines long (including comments, and 300 lines of hexadecimal constants) which is simply a port of the original code

That's not a complicated framework with dozens of modules. It can't have regular announcement about milestones reached. It just works... You'll probably have 1 change in the next few years due to a security issue found by a particularly smart security researcher, but you won't have a community built around that, improvements are not expected as the original algorithm is already implemented

Tests are here to prove the consistency with the C version, I would choose it

Comment: I created issues to address each of my worries, and now it looks like the project is getting a bit of activity after all :-) I decided to integrate this library and it seems to work well so far.